# Deploy ASP.NET Web Application using Publish-AzWebApp

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I want to deploy asp.net Web App on Azure. I want to use Publish-AzWebApp cmdlet for this. Can this be done?

I have tried building the Web App using MSBuild and then zipping the artifacts created after the build. Then using Publish-AzWebApp, I tried deploying the artifacts. But it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

I am running the following command for build:

```
dotnet build WebApp\project.sln /nologo /p:PublishProfile=Release /p:PackageLocation="C:\path\to\Package\" /p:OutDir="C:\path\to\Output\" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /maxcpucount:1 /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="C:\path\to\package.zip"
```

After this I am running:

```
Publish-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Name $webappname -ArchivePath C:\path\to\package\archive.zip -Force
```

The deployment completes without any error but when I open the webapp:

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

This tells me that the package is not deployed successfully and there is some issue is deploying.

Comment: How about the result if you publish the package from local directly without Azure devops?

Comment: I am creating this package locally and then running the Publish-AzWebApp cmdlet in powershell. @LeoLiu-MSFT

Comment: So, you will still have this issue when you creating this package locally and then running the Publish-AzWebApp cmdlet in powershell?

Comment: yes I have tried building the package in two ways-1) using the dotnet build command 2) building using vs. After the build process, I am compressing the files and then running the Publish-AzWebApp but I am facing the issue. When I am deploying the web app to the azure from VS directly, it is working. But not from command line.

Comment: @CaptainLevi Do you have an `index.html` or some default document in your project? `https://<your-app>.azurewebsites.net/index.html`?